# When to use defer service provider?

Tags: laravel, deferred, service-provider

I read the laravel doc saying,

> If your provider is only registering bindings in the service
>   container, you may choose to defer its registration until one of the
>   registered bindings is actually needed.

I don't understand what is "only registering bindings". I google and read many article, but I didn't find the answer.
Could you help me to understand it!

Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Laravel Documentation about [Bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding). In short - it tells the service container what to return when some class or interface is needed. (You can understand more by reading about Dependency Injection and Dependency Injection in PHP).  But Laravel Service providers are not only limited to binding classes in the container. Inside the providers you can point to routes folders, register view() composers, etc...

If you don't have any other code in your Service provider besides registering bindings, than you can defer it so that the code would work faster. But if, for instance, you have a second routes folder that you register in service provider - then you should not defer registering the service provider.

Comment: Good explanation. An example would be the [`HorizonServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/2.0/src/HorizonServiceProvider.php), which does a lot more than just to add bindings to the service container. If you'd defer its execution, some functions would not work until you required one of the services binded in the provider.

Comment: Thank you for answer and example. I have another question.
I know the $this->app->bind(..) is binding to container. However, how do I identify the code of example that is binding another route. The binding($this->app->bind(..)), I think it just bind something to service container, and I didn't find another syntax of laravel to bind something to route. Could you explain it? Thank you!

Comment: @ray 
  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9f313ce9bb5ad49a06ae78d33fbdd1c92a0e21f6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php here is the laravel's binding the routes from `web` and `api` folder

Comment: I think I got what you say.
Your mean is the service provider can do many things. 
If it ONLY do register something to service container, it could be written a DEFER service provider.
Right!?

Comment: Does anyone know then why the [`IdeHelperServiceProvider`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/blob/v2.6.2/src/IdeHelperServiceProvider.php) is deferred, but has a `boot` method?